# Reading Race results from a text file in Java

Tags: java, file-io, text-files, bufferedreader

For my first phase, I'm trying to read race results from a text file. If every line had the exact same format, there wouldn't be a problem. The part that makes this so difficult is the school names. Here's an example of a line in the text file.

```
1  262  Jackson Bertoli (12) Terre Haute South  15:29.1 4:59
```

Each school may have 1,2, or 3 words in its name. So I tried to look for an integer (the time) after the school name and just stop the search for words in the school name there. But I'm having problems taking my value from the reader.next(); and plugging it into the part of the code that evaluates a string from an integer because one uses void and the other uses static. Plus it's having trouble recognizing my variables schoolnext and schoolnext2 throughout the whole code.

It's pretty lengthy, but this is my first big boy program and I would GREATLY appreciate some help with what I have, or different methods I should try. Thanks in advance for all the time you spent looking through it!

```
    /* Original program done by Donald Bough started 11/01/13
    * Cross Country results experimenter!
    * Put your results from indianarunner.com in a .txt file, plug them into the program,       and 
 * you should "eventually be able to" modify your own time or others in the text file
 * to see how it would've affected team places and points.
 * 
 * As of 11/04/13 I'm stuck figuring out how to tell, when scanning the text file, how many words make
 * up the school name, then printing off the rest of the results according to that number. This is the
 * beginning phase where I'm just trying to re-print off what the results already have basically.
 * Once I figure this out, I plan on taking those variables and actually doing the math with it.
 */

import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class myreadfile {
    //Setting up my variables
    int setschool = 0;
    int setschool2 = 0;
    String schoolnext;
    String schoolnext2;
    private Scanner reader;


    //Opening my text file with the race results. This part works 100%
    public void openfile(){
        try{
            reader = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Donalds\\Java\\Partsemistateresults.txt"));
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("This file does not exist");
        }
    }



    // Taking care of the first line of words we don't want to deal with. This also works 100%
        public void firstline(){

                String a = reader.next();
                String b = reader.next();
                String c = reader.next();
                String d = reader.next();
                String e = reader.next();
                String f = reader.next();
                String g = reader.next();


            System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s" , a , b, c , d ,e , f, g);
        }


    //tells if a string is an integer. Everything from now on gets uncertain and sticky.

        public static boolean isInteger(String schoolnext) {
        try { 
            Integer.parseInt(schoolnext); 
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
            // This isn't an integer, so the number 2 is telling us we have a string
            //I want to move onto the next word since it's another name in the 
            //school. Now go back down to the readfile method.
            int setschool=+2;
            return false; 
        }
        //Is an integer. We now know schoolnext took the value of an integer. This 
        //integer would be the time part of the race results. Signal to move past 
        //the attempt in finding school names. Now go back down to the readfile method.
        int setschool =+1;
        return true;
    }



    //This is where the program goes after deciding we had another word in the school na,e/
    public static boolean isInteger2(String schoolnext2) {
        try { 
            Integer.parseInt(schoolnext2); 
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
            //schoolnext2 turns out to be a string, that's three school word names. DONE
            int setschool2=+2;
            return false; 
        }
        //schoolnext2 turns out to be an integer, we're done. schoolnext2 value is the time value
        int setschool2 =+1;
        return true;
    }



    // Meat of the code, goes through all the lines
     public void readfile(){
        while(reader.hasNext()){
            //These are going to always be in this order, makes it do-able and simple.
            String place = reader.next();
            String bib = reader.next();
            String firstname = reader.next();
            String lastname = reader.next();
            String grade = reader.next();
            String school = reader.next() ;
            String schoolnext = reader.next();


        /*  *** Here is where I have trouble. All the schools have a different amount of words
             in their school name. You will now see my attempt at telling when the next part of the 
             race results line is part of the school name or the time ***              */


            // If setschool== 1, it is an integer. Making schoolnext in this case our time string
            //from the race results. Then we print the rest off.
                        if (setschool == 1) {
                            String pace = reader.next();
                            System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n" , place, bib, firstname, 
                            lastname, grade, school, schoolnext, pace);
                        }

            // If setschool was == 2, the next word isn't an integer, its another school name.
            // So we continue on with trying to find if the next string is the race results time
            //or another school name
            if (setschool == 2){
                String schoolnext2 = reader.next();





                //The most words a school has is 3, so once we know the third string is also a word,
                //we can can print off the 3 school strings which are representing each word of the 
                //school.
                if(setschool2 == 2){
                    String time = reader.next();
                    String pace = reader.next();
                    System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n" , place, bib, firstname, 
                    lastname, grade, school, schoolnext, schoolnext2, time, pace);
                }

                //The third word was an integer, our time from the race results. So now we print off
                //the two other Strings and realize schoolnext2 took on the schoolnext2 value
                if(setschool2 == 1){
                    String pace = reader.next();
                    System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n" , place, bib, firstname, lastname,
                    grade, school, schoolnext, schoolnext2, pace);
                }


            }







        }
    } 


    //Closing the file for good programming
    public void closefile(){
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the method `reader.nextInt()`. It finds the next integer while scanning.

Comment: That would make my life a lot easier I suppose. Would this skip over "word" strings and go straight to the next integer?

Comment: yes, it will find only integers while skipping everything else.

[Scanner Object in Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)